# How to get an HTML element from another page without using jQuery or AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the ID of a `td` that is in another page without using Jquery or AJAX.

```
<td id="message"></td>
```

Comment: Are the two pages hosted on the same domain? If yes, you could look into iframe, and how to access its document.

Comment: yes they are in the same domain

Comment: thank you i follow the page structure and i finally find the emplacement

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

var x=document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].id;

0 is the index value of that `td` element . You will get the Id value from the variable `x` .

Comment: at first the td is empty when i click a button in the current page i want to write some text in the td that is in the other page